# Rewriting path when using nginx ingress for path based routing

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to combine a couple of our microservices using an nginx ingress controller on kubernetes using path based routing.

Here's the scenario:

http://myapi.develop.mydomain.com/data-service/request  -> goes to service name
http://myapi.develop.mydomain.com/model-service/request  -> goes to service name

My issue is that when the url/path hits the backend service, it's got the url from the request with it.

So `/data-service/request` hits the app as `/data-service/request` and need it to just hit the app as `/request` (but still show to the user as `/data-service/request`)

Trying to look at using the ingress rewrite rule from here:
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/

Although not too sure whether this is going to change the url for the user or just from the ingress to the service.  We need the url to stay the same to the end user and the changes to be just within the cluster.

Here's the ingress yaml we are using:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapi-ingress
  namespace: mynamespace
  uid: 
  resourceVersion: ''
  generation: 1
  creationTimestamp: '2021-11-16T15:12:42Z'
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  managedFields:
    - manager: kubectl-create
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
      time: '2021-11-16T15:12:42Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:metadata':
          'f:annotations':
            .: {}
            'f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target': {}
        'f:spec':
          'f:ingressClassName': {}
          'f:rules': {}
    - manager: nginx-ingress
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
      time: '2021-11-16T15:12:42Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:status':
          'f:loadBalancer':
            'f:ingress': {}
  selfLink: /apis/networking.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/ingresses/myapi-ingress
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - ip: myip
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: myapi.mynamespace.mydomain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /data-service(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: data-service
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: /model-service(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: model-service
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

Anyone any pointers on where i may be going wrong?

Comment: I would like to reproduce this issue locally - which Kubernetes version are you using?

Comment: Just recently upgraded it to 1.21.2

Comment: I tried it locally with [nginx image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) and it's working fine. How is your application checking logs? Could you share exactly Ingress resource yaml that you applying? Could you check behaviour using nginx image (you can find requests using `kubectl logs {nginx-pod-name}`?

Comment: No joy as yet. I'll try and grab the logs

Answer (score 0):

There could be issue due the API version you are using

Does your K8s support ingress API version `networking.k8s.io/v1beta1` ?

`networking.k8s.io/v1beta1` insted of `networking.k8s.io/v1` and other minor changes

Try with :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2

  name: example
  # namespace: foo
spec:
  rules:
    - host: [your ip address].sslip.io
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: registry-app-server
              servicePort: 8761
            path: /eureka/(.*)
          - backend:
              serviceName: api-gateway-server
              servicePort: 7000
            path: /api(/|$)(.*)
```